# Magento 2 Get Event When User View List Product, Sorting, Filter, Clear Options, Pagination, Add Wish List

Tags: magento2, javascript, event-observer, knockoutjs, magento2.3.5

I am using Magento 2.3.5-p2

As stated in the title, I want to capture an event by the user when the user does any of the processes below

- User View List Product
- User Sort Product
- User Filter Product
- User Clear Options
- User Go Through Pagination
- User Add Item To Wish List

I can't seem to understand how the event is triggered in Magento 2 and how do I make the process to capture this event by the user using knockout js or any other relevant method

Currently what I am doing is by finding the desired value from URL parameter or by using jquery to get desired value such as number of product appearing in each page result

**For example:**
`$('.product-item-info').length`

The reason I want to capture this event is to make the process of executing the Google Tag Manager data layer easily, the code that I will put in is as below

```
require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){

    dataLayer.push({
        'event': 'trackEvent',
        'eventDetails.category': 'product listing engagement',
        'eventDetails.action': 'show number of results',
        'eventDetails.label': product_list_limit+' of '+$('span.toolbar-number')[0].outerText
    });

})
```

Thus having to do one by one just to process for one event is really hard and time-consuming

Hope! Magento 2 experts can advise in a better way.